# Relay Compiler cannot compile Graph.Cool GraphQL schemas with multiple inheritance

Tags: relayjs

I am using a generated schema from Graph.Cool that has the User type implementing two interfaces: Node and AnonymousUser.  This looks like standard multiple inheritance.  The Relay Compiler rejects this, however if I use an ampersand it works (implements Node & AnonymousUser vs. implements Node, AnonymousUser) and I'm not sure why.  Anyone have some background on the correct syntax, or if this sounds like a bug?

> COMPILER ERROR OUTPUT:
>   $ relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./env/schema.graphql Error:
>   Error loading schema. Expected the schema to be a .graphql or a .json
>   file, describing your GraphQL server's API. Error detail:
>
> GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Unexpected Name "AnonymousUser"
>       at syntaxError (/Users/kieran/Git/integer.systems/node_modules/graphql/error/syntaxError.js:24:10)
>       at unexpected (/Users/kieran/Git/integer.systems/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:1322:33)
>       at parseDefinition (/Users/kieran/Git/integer.systems/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:152:9)
>       at parseDocument (/Users/kieran/Git/integer.systems/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:110:22)
>       at parse (/Users/kieran/Git/integer.systems/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:38:10)
>       at getSchema (/Users/kieran/Git/integer.systems/node_modules/relay-compiler/bin/relay-compiler:260:28)
>       at /Users/kieran/Git/integer.systems/node_modules/relay-compiler/bin/relay-compiler:103:19
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at step (/Users/kieran/Git/integer.systems/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
>       at /Users/kieran/Git/integer.systems/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:28:13
>       at getSchema (/Users/kieran/Git/integer.systems/node_modules/relay-compiler/bin/relay-compiler:262:12)
>       at /Users/kieran/Git/integer.systems/node_modules/relay-compiler/bin/relay-compiler:103:19
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at step (/Users/kieran/Git/integer.systems/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
>       at /Users/kieran/Git/integer.systems/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:28:13
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7) error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed. Exit code: 1

```
SCHEMA --------------------------------------------------

type User implements Node, AnonymousUser {  
  createdAt: DateTime!
  email: String
  id: ID!
  isVerified: Boolean!
  password: String
  secret: String!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
}
/* this works: type User implements Node **&** AnonymousUser { ...  */

# An object with an ID
interface Node {
  # The id of the object.
  id: ID!
}

# It's an interface
interface AnonymousUser {
  secret: String
  isVerified: Boolean!
}
```

Comment: Have the same issue, replacing the `,` with an `&` solves the issue. I've opened an issue on github here >> [Issue 2364](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/2364)

Answer (score 0):

It is likely because your schema generating package is using its own out-dated `graphql` sub-dependency which prints the schema in a syntax that is incompatible with your current `relay-compiler`.

I'm not sure how exactly you generate your schema. I'm using `get-graphql-schema` and adding the following into my `package.json` solves the problem for me:

```
"resolutions": { 
  "get-graphql-schema/graphql": "^0.13.0"
}
```

If you're using another package, just replace `get-graphql-schema` with it. The idea is to get your schema generating package using newer version of `graphql`.